# no se ejecuta correctamente el código en Arduino

Tags: arduino

Soy totalmente nuevo en esto pero tengo este inconveniente, estoy probando el demo que trae por default las librerías de blynk, pero me comenta que tengo un error me dice que no tengo bien el espacio y que por eso no puede compilarse correctamente. adjunto el código y el erro que me muestra en consola.

```
void setup() {
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
// but actually the LED is on; this is because
// it is active low on the ESP-01)
delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

Error de compilación

```
Executable segment sizes:
IROM   : 228624          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 
IRAM   : 26756   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 
DATA   : 1248  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
RODATA : 688   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
BSS    : 24880 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
El Sketch usa 257316 bytes (24%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 1044464 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 26816 bytes (32%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 55104 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 81920 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

El código compila bien. Lo que muestras es el resultado de la compilación:

```
El Sketch usa 257316 bytes (24%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 1044464 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 26816 bytes (32%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 55104 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 81920 bytes.
```

Son estadísticas del programa: espacio ocupado por el código y espacio ocupado por variables en memoria RAM.

Sólo te queda subir el compilado a la placa.

Comment: Fijate que me aparece error me dice que el puerto no esta conectado

Comment: Ya lo compile pero me aparece ese error que el puerto serial no esta conectado esto me dice = Puerto serie no seleccionado.

Comment: Ese no es un error de código; el PC no detecta nada conectado en el puerto USB. A veces pasa. Mira en Tools->Ports y selecciona la puerta donde está conectada la placa.

Comment: Correcto amigo eses era el problema te agradezco mucho el problema era el puerto que no tenia instalado los drivers y lo que comentabas no era un error funciona al 100 muchas gracias.